# Limits of expectation of a function

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, limits

Suppose that $g(x,y)$ is a smooth function with respect to $x$ and $y$, and that it is bounded on the domain of interest: $a\leq g(x,y)\leq b$, with $a$ and $b$ being real constants.

Now let $(X)_n$ and $(Y)_n$ be sequences of positive random variables, and denote by $X_n$ and $Y_n$ the $n$-th element of each sequence.  $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are not necessarily independent.

The following fact is known about $(Y_n)$: $P\left(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{Y_n}{f(n)}=c\right)=1$, i.e. a sequence $\left(\frac{Y}{f(n)}\right)_n$ converges to a constant $c$ almost surely. Here $f(n)$ is a smooth function of $n$ (though not necessarily bounded).

I am interested in taking the following limit of expectation (over both $X$ and $Y$):

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} E\left[g\left(X_n,\frac{Y_n}{f(n)}\right)\right]$$

Can I "replace" $\frac{Y_n}{f(n)}$ with $c$, reducing the evaluation of the limit above to evaluation of $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} E\left[g\left(X_n,c\right)\right]$ and thus making it a lot easier, or is it a no-no?  If not, what additional constraints of $g(x,y)$, $(X)_n$ and $(Y)_n$ would allow such replacement?

Comment: If I'm reading your question right, though $f$ wasn't defined anywhere you might as well assume the sequence $(Y_n)$ converges pointwise to the constant function $c$ a.s. Is that so? And if so, does it follow that the sequence $g(X_n,Y_n)-g(X_n,c)$ converges pointwise to zero a.s.?

Comment: $f(n)$ is a smooth function of $n$ though not necessarily bounded -- I edited the question to reflect that.  I would agree with you about pointwise convergence, except that I am scared of the expectation operator...  hence the question.

Comment: Yes, but you don't actually use the $Y_n$'s anywhere, except as $Z_n:=\frac{Y_n}{f(n)}$. What about the 2nd part of my question?

Comment: That is a very good question, and I am not sure how to show that...